# How to make my Matplotlib graph embed in a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been messing around with Tkinter and embedded graphs and from a tutorial I found on the net, I have been able to make the following snippet of code work perfectly:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg # NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 

root = Tk()

# Typical matplotlib code

f = Figure(figsize = (4,3), dpi = 100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
a.plot([1,2,4,3,5,7,6,7,8,8,9,6,7,8,7,5,6,4,3,4,3,2,1])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is I have not been able to incorporate the idea into a program I have been working on (Collatz Conjecture algorithm). What I'm trying to do is to plot a graph of the iteration data points but the graph does not display, notwithstanding the fact that the relevant portions of code in my script and the example snippet are identical. See my code below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk()
root.title("Collatz  Conjecture")

import textwrap

# Matplotlib imports

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg # NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 


 # Functions

lst = []

def collatz(num):
    lst.clear()
    while num != 1:
        lst.append(num)

        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = int(num / 2)

        else:
            num = int(3 * num + 1)

def main(event):
    num = int(input.get())

    collatz(num)


    output1.delete(1.0, END)
    output1.insert(END, lst)
    output2.delete(1.0, END)
    output2.insert(END, "Number of iterations: " + str(len(lst)))



lbl1 = Label(root, width = 20, text = "Type in number\n & press Enter")
lbl1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
lbl2 = Label(root, width = 40, text = "THE COLLATZ CONJECTURE")
lbl2.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

input = Entry(root, width = 20, bg = "light grey")
input.grid(row = 1, padx = 6, sticky = E)
input.get()
input.bind("<Return>", main)

# Matplotlib Graph - typical code

f = Figure(figsize = (4,3), dpi = 100)                  # Create the figure
a = f.add_subplot(111)                                  # Add subplot
a.plot(lst)
                                            # Plot data in background

# Canvas
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 6, column = 0)         
canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row = 6, column = 0)

# canvas = Canvas(root, width= 350, height= 350, bg = "white")
# canvas.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = (5,5), pady = (5,5))

bt1 = Button(root, width = 10, text = "About")
bt1.grid(row = 7, column = 0, pady = (5,7))

output1 = Text(root, wrap = WORD, width = 50, height = 7, bg =   "light grey")  # Note word wrap attribute
output1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = (5,1), sticky = W)
output2 = Text(root, width = 50, height = 1, bg = "white")
output2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)


def about():

    messagebox.showinfo("About", "The Collatz conjecture states that if you pick any positive whole number, and if its even, you divide it by two and if its odd, you multiply it by three and add one, and if you repeat this procedure often enough, the number that you started with will eventually reduce to one and if you play this game for long enough, your friends will eventually stop calling to see if you want to hang out ")

btn1 = Button(root, text = "About", command = about)
btn1.grid(row = 7, column = 0, pady = (5,7))


root.mainloop()
```

I'm pretty sure its an indent problem and that I'm going to be very embarrassed when someone points out my novice mistake but I've tried moving the code around in seeminlgly every possible way but without success.

Could someone please have a look at it and tell me not only where I went wrong but more importantly, WHY its wrong.

Comment: It looks like you don't update the plot after the data input. Also please rename the input variable as it is a built-in function name.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is fundamental. Your tkinter window loop keeps refreshing the plot canvas so you don't get to see the data. What you could do instead is take the canvas out of your window loop and stick it in the main function.

Obviously there are other/better solutions but I hope this one highlights the issue you are facing.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk()
root.title("Collatz  Conjecture")

import textwrap

# Matplotlib imports

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg # NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 


 # Functions

lst = []

def collatz(num):
    lst.clear()
    while num != 1:
        lst.append(num)

        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = int(num / 2)

        else:
            num = int(3 * num + 1)

def main(event):
    num = int(inp_ut.get())

    collatz(num)


    output1.delete(1.0, END)
    output1.insert(END, lst)
    output2.delete(1.0, END)
    output2.insert(END, "Number of iterations: " + str(len(lst)))
    # Generate the data and populate the canvas once. 
    f = Figure(figsize = (4,3), dpi = 100)                  # Create the figure
    a = f.add_subplot(111)                                  # Add subplot
    a.plot(lst)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 6, column = 0)         
    canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row = 6, column = 0)


lbl1 = Label(root, width = 20, text = "Type in number\n & press Enter")
lbl1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
lbl2 = Label(root, width = 40, text = "THE COLLATZ CONJECTURE")
lbl2.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

inp_ut = Entry(root, width = 20, bg = "light grey")
inp_ut.grid(row = 1, padx = 6, sticky = E)
inp_ut.get()
inp_ut.bind("<Return>", main)

# Canvas
# canvas = Canvas(root, width= 350, height= 350, bg = "white")
# canvas.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = (5,5), pady = (5,5))

bt1 = Button(root, width = 10, text = "About")
bt1.grid(row = 7, column = 0, pady = (5,7))

output1 = Text(root, wrap = WORD, width = 50, height = 7, bg =   "light grey")  # Note word wrap attribute
output1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = (5,1), sticky = W)
output2 = Text(root, width = 50, height = 1, bg = "white")
output2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)


def about():

    messagebox.showinfo("About", "The Collatz conjecture states that if you pick any positive whole number, and if its even, you divide it by two and if its odd, you multiply it by three and add one, and if you repeat this procedure often enough, the number that you started with will eventually reduce to one and if you play this game for long enough, your friends will eventually stop calling to see if you want to hang out ")

btn1 = Button(root, text = "About", command = about)
btn1.grid(row = 7, column = 0, pady = (5,7))


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What? I think your comment made much more sense than this answer. Here you create a new figure for each button press. That seems undesired.